# Could someone explain this notation and line inthe transcendence proof of $\pi$?

Tags: notation, transcendental-numbers

In the following linked proof for the transcendence of pi https://fermatslibrary.com/s/the-transcendence-of-pi, the author uses the notation $\theta_1(x)=(e^{\alpha_1}+1)(e^{\alpha_2}+1)(e^{\alpha_3}+1)...(e^{\alpha_n}+1)=0$ where $\alpha_1=i\pi, \alpha_2, \alpha_3,...,\alpha_n$.

I'm unsure what the subscript $1$ in $\theta_1(x)$ is referring to here, how would it differ from $\theta_2(x)$ and how exactly $\theta(x)$ is a function of $x$?

Lastly, can someone just explain how $\theta_1(x)=(e^{\alpha_1}+1)(e^{\alpha_2}+1)(e^{\alpha_3}+1)...(e^{\alpha_n}+1)=0$ implies that the elementary symmetric polynomials of $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3,...,\alpha_n$ are all rational numbers because from my understanding, the line  $\alpha_1=i\pi, \alpha_2, \alpha_3,...,\alpha_n$ means that a symmetric polynomial such as $\displaystyle \sum_{1≤j<i≤n}\alpha_i\alpha_j=\binom{n}{2}\pi^{2}$, which is clearly not rational.

Comment: I do not see the expression $\theta_1(x)=(e^{\alpha_1}+1)\cdots (e^{\alpha_n}+1)$ anywhere in the text. All I see is: 1) the definition of $\theta_1(x)$ as an element of $\Bbb Z[x]$ such that $x=i\pi$ is a solution of $\theta_1(x)=0$; 2) the definition of $\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_n$ as the roots of $\theta_1$ with the caveat that $\alpha_1=i\pi$ specifically; 3) the identity $(e^{\alpha_1}+1)\cdots(e^{\alpha_n}+1)=0$.

Comment: The elementary symmetric polynomials calculated in the sequence of the roots of a polynomial $p$ are equal, up to a sign, to the coefficients of $p$ divided by the leading coefficient of $p$. If $p\in\Bbb Z[x]$, then they are rational.

Comment: the subscript doesn't mean much...the author plans to introduce several polynomials and chooses to index them with subscripts. Also it is clear that $\theta_1(x)$ is *not* equal to that product.